# WinDbg runaway command output explained

Tags: performance, cpu, windbg

I have a production CPU issue, after days of regular activity suddenly the CPU starts to peak. I've saved the dump file and run the !runaway command to get the list of highest CPU time consuming threads. the output is below:

> User Mode Time
>     Thread       Time
>     21:110       0 days 10:51:39.781
>     19:f84       0 days 10:41:59.671
>      5:cc4       0 days 0:53:25.343
>     48:74        0 days 0:34:20.140
>     47:1670      0 days 0:34:09.812
>     13:460       0 days 0:32:57.640
>      8:14d4      0 days 0:19:30.546
>      7:d90       0 days 0:03:15.000
>     23:1520      0 days 0:02:21.984
>     22:ca0       0 days 0:02:08.375
>     24:72c       0 days 0:02:01.640
>     29:10ac      0 days 0:01:58.671
>     27:1088      0 days 0:01:44.390

As you can see, the output shows I've 2 threads: 21 & 19, that consumes more than 20 hours of CPU time combined ,I was able to track the callstack of 1 of those threads like so:

> ~21s
>   !CLRStack
>
> the output doesn't matter at the moment, let's call it the "X callstack"

What I would like, is an explanation about the !runaway command output. from what I understand, a dump file is a snapshot of the current state of the application. so my questions are:

1. How can the runaway command shows 10:51 hours value for thread 21, when the dumping process only took a few seconds?
2. Does it mean that the specific "instance" of the X callstack I've found with the !CLRStack command is hang more than 10 hours? or it's the total time the 21 thread executed his whole X callstacks executions? If so, it seems strange that the 21 thread responsible for so many executions of the X callstacks. As I know the origin is a web request (the runtime should assign a random thread for each call)

I've a speculation that may answer those 2 questions:

Maybe the windbg calculate the time by taking the thread callstack actual time and dividing it by the scope of the dumping process, so if for example the specific execution of the X callstack took 1 second and the whole dumping process took 3 seconds (33%), while the process was running for total of 24 hours the output will show:

8 hours (33% of 24 hours)

Am I right, or completely got it wrong?

Comment: The `!runaway` command only presents the amount of CPU time the thread has spent since it was created. It may or may not have anything to do with the callstack at the time the dump was taken. If you want to see the time spent in each function in the call tree, you'll need to [use a profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx). (By the way, you can glean a bit more information about CPU vs. wall time with `!runaway 7`.)

Comment: The usertime and kerneltime are copied to dump from a kernelmode struct member kthread  it is updated on certain interval  when you dump the last updated time is copied and shown by windbg  windbg just displays  the stuff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*This answer is intended to be comprehensible for the OP. It's not intended to be correct into all bits and bytes.*

> [...] and dividing it by the scope of the dumping process [...]

This understanding is probably the root of all evil: dumping a process only gives you the state of the process at a certain *point* in time. The duration of dumping the process is 0.0 seconds, since all threads are suspended during the operation. (so, relative time for your process, nothing has changed and time is standing still; of course wall clock time changes)

You are thinking of dumping a process as monitoring it over a longer period of time, which is not the case. Dumping a process just takes time because it involves disk activity etc.

So no, there is no "scope" and thus you cannot (it's really hard) measure performance issues with crash dumps.

> How can the runaway command shows 10:51 hours value for thread 21, [...]

How can your C# program know how long the program is running if you only have a timer event that fires every second? The answer is: it uses a variable and increases the value.

That's roughly how Windows does it. Windows is responsible for thread scheduling and each time it re-schedules threads, it updates a variable that contains the thread time.

When writing the crash dump, the information that was collected by the OS long time ago already, is included in the crash dump.

> [...] when the dumping process only took a few seconds?

Since the crash dump is taken by a thread of WinDbg, the time for that is accounted on that thread. You would need to debug WinDbg and do `!runaway` on a WinDbg thread to see how much CPU time that took. Potentially a nice exercise and the `.dbgdbg` (debug the debugger) command may be new to you; other than that, this particular case is not really helpful.

> Does it mean that the specific "instance" of the X callstack I've found with the !CLRStack command is hang more than 10 hours?

No. It means that at the point in time when you created the crash dump, that specific method was executed. Not more, not less.

This information is unrelated to `!runaway`, because the thread may have been doing something totally different for a long time, but that ended just a moment ago.

> or it's the total time the 21 thread executed his whole X callstacks executions?

No. A crash dump does not contain such detailed performance data. You need a performance profiler like JetBrains dotTrace do get that information. A profiler will look at callstacks very often, then aggregate identical call stacks and derive CPU time per call stack.

Comment: Great answer. The kernel stores the execution time; so an API call is made by the MiniDumpWriteDump API to get that information, similar to the way handle information is retrieved. High execution time emphatically means the *opposite* of a hang. You have a busy process. Either it is in a loop or it is just processing lots of requests.

Comment: Thomas, thank you for your detailed answer! I was able to verify your answer by creating a console application that runs 3 threads that execute different callstacks like so with  "----" repesents time  ----thread1 start---thread1 finished----thread2&3 starts---thread 2 finished-----thread3 finished---- I took a dump every "---" and debugged it with Windbg. Unfortunately Your answer is correct :) I would need to take multiple dumps samples in order find the issue. I've found the following profiler, it should do the trick:  https://github.com/jitbit/cpu-analyzer