# In windbg, is there any way to sort the threads based on the last activity?

Tags: debugging, windbg

Our application is getting hung intermittently. We got the memory dump and I loaded it to windbg. There are more than 100 threads it shown in the windbg.

I want to know what is the recent thread got executed before the hang occured. So I want to sort the threads based on the last activity. Is there any way/command to check that?

Comment: Sorry but why the question is downvoted? Atleast give some explanation before down voting it?

Comment: Debugging hang dumps requires lots of experience, and "sort the threads based on last activity" isn't really necessary. Without actually seeing the dump I don't think much more can be discussed. Stack Overflow is less likely to be a good place for such questions. You'd better escalate to a more senior guy in your team or simply open a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: You can try `!analyze -v -hang` but if that does not tell you anything, you might want to look into Windows Performance Recorder/Analyzer. It is much better suited to tell you what a thread/process is waiting on but it's a steap learning curve mind you. I'd recommend to download wprui from bruce dawson (I think) to get a head start.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is often called [time travel debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-overview). Unfortunately, it's not possible to see much about how threads have been executing without first [recording a trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/time-travel-debugging-record).

What is available to you is the [`!runaway`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43495426/windbg-runaway-command-output-explained) command which will display a list of threads sorted by execution time since the process started. That can at least give you an idea of which threads are doing the majority of the work.

Aside from those tricks, `!analyze -v`, as mentioned by [Lieven Keersmaekers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52598/lieven-keersmaekers), is always a good starting point for figuring out why a process is hung. And in some circumstances, `!locks` and [DebugDiag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-debug-diagnostics-to-analyze-a-memory-dump) can provide some useful information about the state of the program at the time of the hang.